# unregister broadcastreceiver not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I'm working with dynamically broadcastreceiver and I want to receive events when the airplane mode is toggled.
The problem in steps:

1 - I'm registering my broadcast in fragment.onResume() and unregistering it in fragment.onPause()

2 - when the orientation changes for the first time, the message log show me a message in onResume method (when i'm registering it again)

```
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity my.package.pj.HomeActivity has leaked IntentReceiver my.package.pj.usecases.AirplaneReceiver@3ce61109 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

(i'm unregistering it on onPause, do you remeber remeber?)

3 - when the orientation changes for the second time, the log show me a message in onPause method (when i'm unregistering it again)

```
IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: my.package.pj.usecases.usecases.AirplaneReceiver@3ce61109
```

I put logs to check if everytime that I call registerReceiver i call too the unregisterReceiver and it's working as expected.

I'm thinking that the unregisterReceiver method have a problem and my broadcast receiver isn't unregistered and for any reason this receiver never registered more. Do you know what i'm doing wrong or if this is an android knowlled bug?

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    mReceiver = new AirplaneReceiver();
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

public void onPause(){
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: are you sure mReceiver is never null?

Comment: Do you have other places where mReceiver is referenced? Post those as well.

Comment: remove : setRetainInstance(true); - I think retaining the fragment is causing the problem. onCreate will not get called if the fragment is retained and a configuration change occurs. Also use getActivity().getApplicationContext() to gain your context in your fragment.

Comment: I'm sure my receiver is never null and doesn't have other place that mReceiver is referenced. I can't remove the setRetainInstance(true) beacuse this will impact in anothers important things. Maybe the problem exists because i'm using getActivity as a context. I will test the getApplicationContext method to check it.

Comment: In my tests I used the LocalBroadcastManager to register and unregister the airplane receiver and this bug not happens, BUT the receiver is not triggered when i toggle the airplane mode. Is possible to use LocalBroadcastManager to register Android Receivers?